# MySQL Retrieve repeatin results using "in" condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Of all aspects of coding, SQL is my weakest skill, so please forgive me if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about, because I probably don't!

**Situation:**
Building a shopping cart where the table named "cart" has a field named "products" of type VARCHAR 255, and the value of "products" will be a comma delimited string. Each element of the string will be a number which represents the id of a product from the "products" table.

A customer's record may contain a value in the "products" field that looks like 1,1,1,2,3. This would mean the customer has added three of item 1, one of item 2, and one of item 3.

**Problem:**
So, here is the sql statement I have presently, but the problem is I need a sql statement that will return repeat product data from the product table:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name,price 
  FROM products 
 WHERE id in ('1','1','1','2','3')
```

The result of that will be a set of three items from the "products" table, 1 and 2 and 3. In other words, it doesn't give me the product data for the three '1's, it only gives me a distinct value. Not 3 values from the products table, but 5 values from the products table, where the first three results are identical, because they are the same product_id=1.

I need a sql statement that will give me the redundant product information, because after all, a person can order three widgets with the product_id = 1.

**cart:**

```
id INT(15)
uid VARCHAR(32)
email VARCHAR(100)
products VARCHAR(255)
date DATETIME
checkout TINYINT(1)
```

**products:**

```
id INT(15)
product_id  varchar(32)
product_name varchar(128)
product_associations varchar(255)
short_description   varchar(255)
long_description    mediumtext
price   varchar(32)
image   varchar(128)
```

My php code:

```
$productslist = str_replace(",","','",$row->products);
$productslist = "'" . $productslist . "'"; echo $productslist;
$sql2 = "SELECT product_id, product_name,price FROM products WHERE id in ($productslist)";
$query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
$i = 0;
if ($query2->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach ($query2->result() as $row2){
        $products[$i]['product_id'] = $row2->product_id;
        $products[$i]['product_name'] = $row2->product_name;
        $products[$i]['price'] = $row2->price;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

...and a result of this query would be:

```
Product ID:  #0001 
Product Name:  "Ducky"
Price:  $1.50

Product ID:  #0002 
Product Name:  "Horse"
Price:  $1499.00

Product ID:  #0003 
Product Name:  "T-shirt"
Price:  $5.00
```

**Update:**
In the interest of best practices, I studied the "normalized" table theory, then rolled back the above scheme of a comma-delimited products field. I created a separate table called "cart_list", with the fields:

```
id
cart_id
product_id
```

...and I simply insert new records for each new "add to cart", keyed to the cart table by the cart_id field, and keyed to the product data through the product_id field.

Comment: i think you need to normalize your field that looks like `1,1,1,2,3`.

Comment: Either `SELECT DISTINCT id` or a `GROUP BY` might work, if you can't prefilter your id list.

Comment: Daniel is correct - you need to use a table that joins cart and products, rather than a comma delimited list.

Comment: Any links to examples?

Comment: Can you give sample data and sample output you want to achieve? A database schema can be helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

a bit ugly but that would do the trick:

```
create temporary table t (id integer);
insert into t(id) values (1),(1),(2),(2),(3);


select product_id, product_name,price from t inner join products where t.id = products.id;

drop table t;
```

Comment: I agree, applying temp table would be a little ugly. Nevertheless, will do the trick.

Comment: Yup. It is an ugly hack. You should normalized your tables. It provides a better solution, and allows the database to do foreign key checking. Example. What happens if item with id if 2 is deleted. How are you going to go in and remove all the ids from the field?